# Does a codex exist for creating meta boxes in taxonomy

Tags: custom-taxonomy, metabox, codex, documentation

I am looking for WordPress official documentation to create meta boxes in a taxonomy. There are many tutorials, but each of them is completely different. I don't want to use any plugins. I need the source code (Right Way - Recommended Method by WordPress ) .

Comment: What exactly do you mean by _create meta boxes in a taxonomy_? Are you talking about `edit-tags.php?taxonomy=your-taxonomy` (i.e., taxonomy overview)? Or `edit-tags.php?action=edit&taxonomy=your-taxonomy&tag_ID=123` (i.e., edit specific term)? Or something else?

Comment: adding custom fields in taxonomy- (edit-tags.php?taxonomy=your-taxonomy) not just in specific term .

Comment: While this is interesting issue, I don't quite feel the form question is asked in is productive. You can search Codex just as well as anyone else, if that is what you need done. I would urge you to focus question on what had you tried and what you have issues with in implementing it.

Comment: Actually I searched the codex but couldn't find anything regarding "creating meta boxes in taxonomy". that's the reason I am asking this question here. Currently I don't have have issues  for creating it ,But I wanted to use the Right Way - Recommended Method by WordPress . to make a right practice.